# jQuery scrollTop/scrollTo blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scrollto, scrolltop

I'm not sure if this is how it works anyway.

I want it so when the user scrolls, after having unclicked the scroll bar and they have scrolled to their desination I can run a function or something. Not running a function 'as' they are scrolling.

Not sure if that makes sense but I appreciate any attempted answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of, as it's a tricky event to trigger. In my case my scroll-wheel (which I always use to scroll web pages) is actually jerky as it stop/starts scrolling.

You could set a delay after which a function is triggered, and if the page continues to scroll then reset the delay. An example can be found in [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/661801-event-after-scrolling).

Hope that helps